# 2 divs on same line won't extend all the way to include text

Tags: html, css

I have two divs I have placed next to each other inside a content-container div, one of them includes a video and some description text and the other includes a scrollbar of random text. However, as you can see in this picture ( http://gyazo.com/1a5b3e559c1f4294b8c05b6c74fc677d ), the content-container doesn't include the description like I wanted (thus making the rounded div content-container not cover it). I have tried to fix it, but I haven't had much luck. Here is a breakdown of my code:

I'll show the CSS first:

```
#content-container3
{
margin-top: 10px;
width: 900px;
repeat-y 100% 0;
border-radius: 5px; 
-moz-border-radius: 5px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
border: 1px solid #575757;
background: #DBDBDB;
}

#content
{
margin-top: 10px;
padding: 5px;
padding-top: 0px;
float: left;
}

#scroll {
height: 358px;
border: 1px solid #999;
width: 239px;
overflow: auto;
margin-top: 10px;
padding: 2px;
}
```

And now onto the HTML

```
    <div id="content-container3">

      <div id="content">

<video id="player_a" class="projekktor" poster="intro.png" title="1v1LB Player" style="background: black;"     width="640" height="360" controls>
   <source src="unorthxdox.mp4" type="video/mp4" />

</video>                <h2 style="padding-top: 10px;">
                Unorthxdox vs CaLeB XII</h2>
<a href="unorthxdox.1v1lb.com">Player's Profile</a> | <a href="oriixa.1v1lb.com">Editor's Profile</a> <br />
<a href="1v1lb.com/vid=220/">Click here to view comment(s) on the game.</a>
</div>
<div id="scroll">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor       incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea     commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla     pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est     laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et     dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea     commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla     pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est     laborum.</p>
</div>
        </div>
```

From the code I have posted, it should be working. I have tried messing with the float and the width and other things such as that and I haven't been able to find a solution. I'm not the best with HTML/CSS, but I would like to be able to at least fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `float: left;` into all three css rules helps.

(But don't forget to clear it after. And anyway, I would take risk and advise you not to use floats. Your markup, you can achieve it by removing `float: left` and adding `display: inline-block;` to `#content` and `#scroll`.)

Comment: Why would you advise against float:left;? BTW that solved the problem, but if floats aren't the best way, then i'd rather use display: inline-block; But when I try to use the inline-block it displays almost there, but slightly distorted. http://gyazo.com/51d9e8bcd53d897a5006f4247aaa3256 As you can see, the #scroll div didn't go all the way to the top like it is supposed to.

Comment: @Achilles Because you fixed its height in css.

Comment: Answering your first question, maybe it's just phobia from old times, when browsers were not cool enough and floats used to ruin pages in all ways you could possibly imagine. Also, you have to remember about `clear` which is annoying.